# Slow querying with stored procedure when querying newer records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry for the wall of text below...

I have a bit of a weird problem here. I have quite a large table that stores message tracking log information from Exchange 2007 for the last couple of days. The record count is in the millions (approx 10-12 million) and once every 30 minutes I am bulk inserting any new logs in from all of our Transport servers via PowerShell scheduled tasks.

Once per night I run a maintenance task to clear down any logs older than a day old so that the table does not get too big, though I would like to keep the logs for a bit longer if I could.

The table is called MessageTracking, and has a primary key which is an IDENTITY int column, **[MessagelogID]** that increments by 1 each record.

There is a non-clustered index on the **[date-time]** column for **[date-time]** asc.

There is a full text index on the Sender and Recipient fields.

Users can search the table by way of a frontend web page I wrote in C# Asp.net. The page allows very basic searching with 4 search fields:

- Start DateTime
- End DateTime
- Sender
- Recipient

This passes the query through to a stored procedure that actually pulls the records back. the stored procedure is called **GetMessageTracking**.

Now onto my strange problem. This query returns results in 0 seconds, quick as lightning:

```
USE [DATABASENAME]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetMessageTracking]
        @maximumRows = 20,
        @startRowIndex = 0,
        @sortExpression = N'[date-time]',
        @SearchStartDate = N'2012-03-27 13:51',
        @SearchEndDate = N'2012-03-27 20:09',
        @SearchSender = N'user@domain.com',
        @SearchRecipient = N'Default'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

If i change the @SearchStartDate parameter to being an hour further along, i.e. **N'2012-03-27 14:51'** then it does not complete for a very very long time.

I can only assume it's having major problems with my datetime index as the full text catalog is generally idle. One of the challenges I have is that I am literally inserting thousands of records an hour and the index (**IX_DateTime**) becomes fragmented very quickly, however I can't think of a great way to stop this happening.

So my questions are two fold really:

1) How can I see what is causing this problem with the queries taking a while when searching for newer records?

2) Any tips for indexing when there are a large number of inserts going on?

I thought maybe it was the Execution Plans causing this strange behaviour but no that seems OK. I tried adding the WITH RECOMPILE option to the queries and that made no difference at all. I cleared the execution plan cache as well to no effect.

Pretty sure my problems are entirely down to my indexing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using recompile was a good first step. So we can exclude the possibility that parameter sniffing if the problem.

Please post a screenshot of the execution plan. I guess the problem will become clear that way. My guess is that this is a statistics problem. the query optimizer thinks that there are no rows with DateTime >= N'2012-03-27 14:51' and chooses the wrong plan because of that. Try running sp_updatestats.

As for #2 of your questions: Set the index padding to some value in the range 50-80.

Comment: Can't see an easy way of uploading an image here so I've uploaded it to imgur. Wasn't able to replicate a query tonight that took so long as yesterday, but one I did do that took 26 seconds to run I recorded the execution plan that used. http://i.imgur.com/LXRO6.png - how does this look?

Comment: How many rows did the DateTime-index return and how many rows are in the table? I think the problem is that for some data the fulltext match function sorts out almost all of the rows. This makes it necessary to return many rows from the right part of the query to fill the page size you requested. You can check this by removing the fulltext filter from the query. It should be extremely fast now.

Comment: Regarding point 2 i've set the index to 70% fill factor for a test, however one thing I read before here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459%28v=sql.110%29.aspx is that having a fill factor of less than 100 (or 0) can actually decrease performance when the data is always added to the end of the table. As I am always inserting with an identity column I would assume this applies to me?

Comment: This is generally true, but the data in your index does not get inserted in primary key order. It gets inserted in index order, which might be different. I didn't know if that was the case so I advised that you try it. If it does nothing for you you should revert the change.

Comment: The query actually returned 0 results, because there were no matches on the query that was sent, but in the execution plan on the IX_DateTime it said the number of actual rows was 327392. Are you advising I just search between start and end date and see the performance leaving the Sender and Recipient fields out of the query? if so yes that is very quick to return results but i'm not sure how it helps me exactly!

Comment: This was just a means to identify the problem. We now exactly know what the problem is. Fixing this is very tricky, because we don't know beforehand if the datetime filter or the fulltext filter will be more restrictive. Lets try creating an index on recipient_address and update both indexes WITH FULLSCAN. Let's see if this is enough. Also, please create an index on (DateTime, recipient_address) and on (recipient_address, DateTime). Just for testing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9430/discussion-between-hungryhippos-and-usr)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the large number of INSERT's and DELETE's it's possible that you may have fragmented indexes on your table.  The following script (taken from [SQL Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/10/sql-server-2005-display-fragmentation-information-of-data-and-indexes-of-database-table/)) will give you information on the fragmentation

```
select object_name(i.object_id) as table_name,
       indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), null, null, null, 'detailed') indexstats
inner join sys.indexes i 
   on i.object_id = indexstats.object_id and i.index_id = indexstats.index_id
where indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 20
```

If you find a large amount of fragmentation, you could rebuild or reorganize the indexes.  SQL Authority has another [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/22/sql-server-difference-between-index-rebuild-and-index-reorganize-explained-with-t-sql-script/) that provides the following information.

**Index Rebuild:** This process drops the existing Index and Recreates the index.

```
alter index all on schema.table_name rebuild
```

**Index Reorganize:** This process physically reorganizes the leaf nodes of the index.

```
alter index all on schema.table_name reorganize
```

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions, you and the guy below you, I will check them out when I get the time to do so, maybe tomorrow or later tonight pending other stuff!

Comment: Hi, I'm running this big old script in the SQL jobs once a night at like 02:00 - http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/15/a-more-effective-selective-index-rebuildreorganize-strategy/. Running it right now shows the following:[dbo].[MessageTracking].[IX_DateTime]:
 FRAGMENTATION: 57.3457%
 PAGE COUNT: 40418
 OPERATION: REBUILD
ALTER INDEX [IX_DateTime] ON [dbo].[MessageTracking] REBUILD

Answer (score 0):

I think you've identified your own problem - the fragmentation of indices with the large amount of writing you are doing.

You can help alleviate this problem by tweaking the padding (disk space) alotted for growth of the table and indices.

Comment: I did some work on this the other night with usr who also posted in this thread. We think the problem is with the fulltext index and this is being hit before the datetime index is being used. The fragmentation etc probably doesn't help but if I don't query on the fulltext index at all it returns instantly with results. This is my execution plan - http://i.imgur.com/LXRO6.png - as you can see the first thing it's hitting is the fulltext index. Ideally I want to query the datetime index first I guess so that it has less items to query from the fulltext index.